# Неявное подключение DLL С++ WINAPI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

Пару часов назад писал с вопросом о явном подключении и с горем пополам разобрался, спасибо всем, кто помог. Сейчас встал вопрос о неявном подключении DLL библиотек в проект. Программа должна загружать из библиотеки процедуру обработки диалового окна. Проблема заключается в том, что при объявлении прототипа функции компилятор выдает сообщение "не найдено определение функции Dialog1". Других ошибок при компиляции не возникает, DLL скомпилировалась без проблем. Файл ".lib" в свойствах указан.
**Сам прототип:**

```
 WINGDIAPI BOOL WINAPI Dialog1(GOODS&, HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

**Код DLL:**

```
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // текущий экземпляр
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Текст строки заголовка
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // имя класса главного окна
                                                // создаем пользовательскую структуру****************************************************
struct GOODS {//структура, описывающая изделия на складе
    TCHAR model[20];
    int razmer; // Номер изделия
    int Price;  // Цена изделия
};
//***************************************************************************************


const int N = 100; // Количество образцов изделий на складе
GOODS Stock[N]; //Создадим в памяти массив для всех изделий
GOODS Unit; // Структурные переменные для двух "odnogo izdelia" изделий
DWORD dwCount;//Для функции чтения/записи

              //*****************************************************************************************
const DWORD MaxLength = 250;
__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI Dialog1(GOODS&,HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// Отправить объявления функций, включенных в этот модуль кода:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

//extern "C" { int _afxForceUSRDLL; }
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain2(HMODULE hModule, DWORD u1_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (u1_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance; // Сохранить дескриптор экземпляра в глобальной переменной

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}
//------------------------------------
int static count = 0; //счётчик подсчёта количества введенных экземпляров чего-то там
                      //------------------------------------
WCHAR s_text1[10] = { 0 };
WCHAR s_text2[10] = { 0 };

WCHAR s_text3[10] = { 0 };
WCHAR s_text4[10] = { 0 };

BOOL WINAPI Dialog1(GOODS&, HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND road, hList1;
    static TCHAR str[20], roadName[20];
    //int size = 255;//sizeof(model) / sizeof(ms);
    //int size = sizeof(Stock) / sizeof(GOODS);
    int size = count;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        //получение дескрипторов
        hList1 = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_LIST1);
        //задаём какая радиокнопка будет выделена при запуске
        SendDlgItemMessage(hWnd, IDC_RADIO5, BM_SETCHECK, WPARAM(BST_CHECKED), 0);
        return TRUE;
        //обработка выбора кнопки
    case WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_EDIT1:
            road = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_EDIT1);
            GetWindowText(road, roadName, 20);
            wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s"), roadName);
            break;
        case IDC_LIST1:
            break;
        case IDC_RADIO1:wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Toshiba"));
            SendMessage(hList1, LBS_SORT, 1, 1);
            break;
        case IDC_RADIO2:wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Asus"));
            break;
        case IDC_RADIO3:wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Sony"));
            break;
        case IDC_RADIO4:wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s"), TEXT("Dell"));
            break;
        case IDC_BUTTON2:
            SendMessage(hList1, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (Stock[j].Price > Stock[j + 1].Price) {
                        GOODS temp = Stock[j];
                        Stock[j] = Stock[j + 1];
                        Stock[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s %d"), Stock[i].model, Stock[i].Price);
                SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM(str));
            }
            break;
        case IDC_RADIO5:
            road = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_EDIT1);
            GetWindowText(road, roadName, 20);
            wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s"), roadName);
            break;
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
            //заполнение элементов списка   
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (wcscmp(str, Stock[i].model) == 0) {
                    wsprintf(str, TEXT("%s %d"), Stock[i].model, Stock[i].Price);
                    SendMessage(hList1, LB_RESETCONTENT, 0, 0); //отчистка листбокса
                    SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM(str));
                }
            break;
            return TRUE;
        default: EndDialog(hWnd, 0); break;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Так его наверное надо как `__declspec(dllimport)` объявлять, иначе линкер не узнает, что оно откуда-то импортируется.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при объявление через `__declspec(dllimport)` ошибка в виде "не найдено определение функции Dialog1" сохраняется

Comment: А есть уверенность что формат `lib` соответствует платформе? Что говорит студия при добавлении этой библиотеки в проект? и посмотрите его свойства и экспортируемые функции, после подключения к проекту.

Comment: @NewView формат `lib` 100% соответствует платформе. При добавлении в проект студия ведет себя нормально, никаких уведомлений/оповещений не появилось, добавился без проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы неявным образом использовать функции из DLL-библиотек в своем коде (т.е. требовать от системы автоматическую загрузку DLL-библиотеки в ОЗУ при первой необходимости и проецирование в адресное пространство процесса конкретной ее функции) надо обеспечить выполнение 4 условий:

1. Чтобы эта функция была объявлена в DLL-библиотеке как
   экспортируемая;
2. Чтобы эта функция была объявлена в коде программы как импортируемая;
3. Чтобы имена экспортируемой и импортируемой функции совпадали (на
   этапе компиляции и линковки внешние имена искажаются определенным
   образом, поэтому требуется совпадение не исходных имен функций, а
   искаженных имен);
4. Чтобы при линковке программы был указан именно тот LIB-файл, который
   содержит описание используемой функции в DLL-библиотеке.

По своему опыту скажу, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев при возникновении ошибок такого рода как "Не найдено определение такой-то функции из DLL" связано с невыполнением одного из этих 4 условий (или нескольких сразу).

Когда сталкиваемся с ошибкой "Не найдено определение такой-то функции из DLL", которую не удается решить сходу (потому что "якобы" все написано правильно), можно использовать такой общий алгоритм решения проблемы:

1. Смотрим, что в проекте в настройках линковки указан соответствющий
   lib-файл в списке импортируемых файлов. Для гарантии, что он
   действительно подключается, можем отключить его (если внутри
   программы не одна его функция используется), при этом будем
   наблюдать резкое возрастание такого рода ошибок при линковке.
2. Смотрим, присутствует ли данная функция в секции экспорта внутри DLL
   (помним, что ее имя будет некоторым образом искажено, который
   зависит от системы и способа объявления функции, например, вместо
   имени MyFunc можно обнаружить что-то типа _MyFunc@8). Просмотреть
   секцию импорта можно как обычным чтением файла DLL простым текстовым
   редактором (что не очень удобно), так с помощью какой-либо утилиты,
   которая может интерпретировать PE-заголовок в файле. Лично я обычно
   использую для этих целей hview или w32dsm. Если искомой функции
   нету, то она не объявлена экспортируемой и в этом проблема. Если
   функция имеется, обращаем внимание на то, каким образом искажено ее
   имя.
3. Смотрим, присутствует ли данная функция в секции импорта в коде
   программы и каким образом она искажена. Если ее нет, она не
   импортируется вообще. Если кода программы нет (потому что линковщик
   ругается при линковке проекта), смотрим, какую функцию (с учетом
   искажения имени) требует линковщик. Если имена требуемой и
   экспортируемой функции отличаются, устраняем проблему (меняем способ
   объявления функции либо в программе, либо в DLL, чтобы имена
   искажались одинаково).
4. Если первых 3 условия выполняются, то это скорее всего редкий
   случай, когда используется не та версия LIB-файла (например, из
   предыдущего релиза DLL, которая еще не содержит новой функции).